# GetKnownFolderPath return empty string

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, windows-shell

I 'm using this code (Delphi 7) to retrieve the cookies folder of users, under win7.

```
function MyCookieDir : string;
begin
  result := '';

  if Win32MajorVersion >= 6 then
    result := GetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Cookies, 0, 0);

end;
```

On some PCs, the function returns an empty string. Why ?

Many thanks

Comment: Well, it will return an empty string when running under XP, or when running under XP compat mode.

Comment: You can use SHGetSpecialFolderLocation function (with CSIDL_COOKIES constant) to retrieve the cookies folder

Comment: @SimaWB What makes you think that's any different from using `FOLDERID_Cookies`? Of course it will work on XP, provided that the version check is removed.

Comment: The PCs are on Win7.
Some users may run the app on XP compat mode. But I don't understand why they would, the app is Win7 compatible.
No other idea ?

Comment: Did you check whether `Win32MajorVersion` is actually `>= 6`? It should not be when running in a compatibility mode. In the off chance that it is indeed `>= 6`, did you check `GetKnownFolderPath()` for errors?

Comment: It is actually much easier to avoid the known folder API and use the CSIDL based versions. Then there's no need for version checks. Why are you trying to use known folder rather than CSIDL based approach?

Comment: I don't check for errors on call to GetKnownFolderPath().
CSIDL based version are deprecated since Vista

Comment: @user382591 You should simply ignore what MSDN says about CSIDL and just use those APIs. They work and they will carry on working. MS is not in the habit of removing old APIs that are still being used. On the other hand, if you don't support XP, then you can continue using known folder.

Comment: Ok. I think that GetKnownFolderPath could fail and I should check for erros. Do you know why it could fails ?

Comment: I guess `GetKnownFolderPath` is calling `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, but we can't see that code. Lots of reasons why it could fail. You'd have to check the error code. I've seen a huge number of questions here on SO with people struggling over known folder API when a simple call to the good old fashioned CSIDL APIs would be easier.

Comment: OK thanks I will combine both

Comment: You can't accept an answer provided in a comment. Which of the comments actually solves your problems? Feel free to write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the issue by :

- checking return value of GetKnownFolderPath
- if false is returned, then quering CSIDL

Thanks to Remi and David

Comment: I find it really disappointing that the MSDN topics on known folder API leads people to solutions like this. Using CSIDL would give exactly what you wanted and would be trivial to read and understand.

Comment: Not everything that is accessible via a `KNOWNFOLDERID` is accessible via a `CSIDL`.  That is partly why the KnownFolder API was introduced, to address `CSIDL` limitations.  However, the KnownFolder API works just fine when used correctly.  If people have problems with it, it is because they don't use it correctly.

Comment: Aside from doing an OS version check if needed (which DLL delay loading can help with so you can actually avoid the OS check), it is just as easy to call a single API function that accepts a `KNOWNFOLDERID` as input as it is to call a single API function (or a couple of API functions on old OS versions) that accepts a `CSIDL` as input instead.  This is not rocket science.